# echo %JAVA_HOME% shows differenct location than JAVA_HOME in environment variables

Tags: java

I reinstalled the Java JDK on my computer.

I added environment variable `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71` but when I try:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

the output shows

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
```

I also added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin` to the Path variable

and `Java -version` doesn't work. (doesn't know java name)

Do you know where should I change it?

PS. I'm using windows 7.

Comment: How did you add the environment variable?

Comment: Java -version and java -version give me same result.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind My Comuter -> Properties -> environment variables -> system viariables. and I edited path and added JAVA_HOME

Comment: Is there a JAVA_HOME set in the user variables as well?

Comment: Did you close and re-open the commandline after adding the environment variable and changing the `PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

**Set the JAVA_HOME Variable**

Once you have the JDK installation path:

Right-click the **My Computer** icon on
your desktop and select **Properties**.

Click the **Advanced tab**.

Click the **Environment Variables** button.

Under **System Variables**, click New.

Enter the variable name as **JAVA_HOME**.

Enter the variable value as the installation path for the **Java Development Kit**.

Click **OK**.

Click **Apply Changes**.

You might need to restart windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I restart windows and it helped. now java-version shows:

java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

But when I try to start maven it shows errors:

set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: I changed some values in mvn.bat file: set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=3072M                                          now I have errors:                                                 -Error occurred during initialization of VM
The size of the object heap + perm gen exceeds the maximum representable size